# Angular Material mat-radio-button gives wrong value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use angular material mar-radio-button to select between true and false.
I have set default value but when I click on other radio button, it gives the value of the default selected value.
My Html
[image]

Component

[image]

So the value of the false is automatically set and if I select value of true it still prints out false.

I am using

```
console.log(this.shippingForm.get('signatureReq').value) to print out the value.
```

Comment: Check console to see if you're getting this error: `Error: formGroupName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup`

Also, if possible, please consider creating a stackblitz.

Comment: Could you hover over those underlined marks and tell us what the errors are?

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
<form [formGroup]="shippingForm">
     <mat-radio-group formControlName="signatureReq" (change)="changeRadioValue()">
         <mat-radio-button [value]=true>Option 1</mat-radio-button>
         <mat-radio-button [value]=false>Option 2</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
```

In your typescript

```
this.shippingForm = this.fb.group({
  signatureReq: [false],
})
```

if you are using `[value]="'true'"` it takes value as a string not a boolean. So use `[value]=true`.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-stackoverflow-52122415-solution)

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is what you want to achieve.

In your HTML change it as follows:

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="signatureReq" (change)="changeRadioValue()">
    <mat-radio-button [value]="'true'">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button [value]="'false'">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

The value of **signatureReq** is updated when you click on an option.

See [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-nzuj19) for Demo.

Comment: Here it takes value as a string not a boolean. Use `[value]=true`. Do not use  `[value]="'true'"`.